# Refresh Token Not Working in Production Build

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm currently facing a perplexing issue with my React Native application. Everything works perfectly when I run the app in a development environment, but the same isn't true once I've built it and uploaded to the app stores.

My app uses a decorator for refreshing tokens. This decorator requests an access token from `AsyncStorage` and sets it in the headers of each request. If a `401 Unauthorized` response is received, the decorator tries to refresh the token and perform the request again with the updated token.

The issue I'm having is that this mechanism isn't working when I build the app for production. I've used `Charles` to monitor the app's traffic and found out that the refresh token API isn't being called at all.
Here's a snippet of the decorator code:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpStatusCode } from '@/data/protocols';
import { PubSubEventAdapter } from '@/data/usecases';
import { RefreshToken } from '@/domain/usecases';
import { AsyncStorageAdapter } from '@/infra';

export class AuthorizeHttpClientDecorator implements HttpClient {
  private errorHandlers = {
    RevokedRefreshToken: () => {
      this.listener.publish({ event: 'invalid-refresh-token', data: null });
    },
    PaymentRequired: () => {
      this.listener.publish({ event: 'payment-required', data: null });
    },
  };

  constructor(
    private readonly refreshToken: RefreshToken,
    private readonly storageAdapter: AsyncStorageAdapter,
    private readonly httpClient: HttpClient,
    private readonly listener: PubSubEventAdapter,
  ) {}

  async request({ headers = {}, ...data }: HttpRequest): Promise<HttpResponse> {
    const accessToken = await this.storageAdapter.get('accessToken');
    const refreshTokenValue = await this.storageAdapter.get('refreshToken');

    if (accessToken) {
      const tokenParsed = `Bearer ${JSON.parse(accessToken)}`;
      headers.Authorization = tokenParsed;
    }

    const response = await this.httpClient.request({ headers, ...data });

    if (response.statusCode === HttpStatusCode.unathorized) {
      try {
        const refreshResponse = await this.refreshToken.updateToken({
          refresh_token: JSON.parse(refreshTokenValue),
        });

        await this.storageAdapter.set('accessToken', refreshResponse.access_token);

        const refreshedToken = `Bearer ${refreshResponse.access_token}`;
        headers.Authorization = refreshedToken;

        const newResponse = await this.httpClient.request({ headers, ...data });
        return newResponse;
      } catch (e) {
        const errorHandler = this.errorHandlers[e.constructor.name];
        if (errorHandler) {
          errorHandler();
        }
        throw e;
      }
    }
    return response;
  }
}
```

I've tried several approaches to fix this, including checking CORS policies, verifying API endpoints, adjusting token expiration, examining build configurations, and capturing error logs. I've even thought of issues related to minification and obfuscation of the code in the production build, but I haven't been able to pinpoint the exact cause yet.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or could provide any guidance or insights on what could be causing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!